# Best practice to rebind js widget after ajax/replacement?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a django website with some custom js/widgets i wrote myself. To give an idea of the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input_group_text_clear button").on("click", function (e) {
        data_action = $(this).attr('data-action');
        data_target = $(this).attr('data-target');
        $.each(data_target.split(':'), function(i, target) {
            $("#" + target).val("").trigger("change");
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Now this works very well since i only need to glue this js code to a django widget, tie it to the form and the code is included with the template.

The issue is that often i post forms using ajax and upon failure the rendered form including error/blocks is returned via a json api. I then "replace" the form element with the one containing the errors.

Issue is that i need to rebind the controls; otherwise the control won't work as planned obviously. What i usually do is to extract the "bind" code in a global function and invoke that from the ajax/done handler but i don't really like it because you need to assume what controls are in the form, my question is if there are best practices for such element replacement combined with binding js functions?

Help is greatly appreciated,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegation. Instead of binding your click to the button itself, you should bind it to an element higher in the hierarchy that does not get replaced, then use the selector argument within the call to `on()` to choose the actual element to bind to.

So, given this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <form>
     <div id="input_group_text_clear">
        <button>submit</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And assuming your Ajax replaces everything inside the `<form>`, your code should be:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".input_group_text_clear button", function (e) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that comment Daniel.

I found an option too which is to set "self.helper.include_media = True" (i'm using django crispy forms to render the forms). This effectively ships the javascript code with the form/html and runs it initially, so i don't need to trigger anything manually myself.... I'm not sure if this works on all browsers but at least chrome works.